# Counting fractals modulo "shared complements"

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, fractals, hausdorff-dimension

*Previously [asked at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689792/counting-fractals-via-stagewise-complements?noredirect=1&lq=1):*

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be the space of compact nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (I'm not especially wedded to dimension $2$, so feel free to tweak that if it would lead to a more interesting question) equipped with the Hausdorff metric. Every finite set of contraction maps $F=\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ yields a single contraction map on $\mathscr{H}$, namely $$\hat{F}: X\mapsto \bigcup_{1\le i\le n}f_i[X].$$ Since $\mathscr{H}$ is complete, by Banach's fixed point theorem the map $\hat{F}$ has a unique fixed point $S_F$. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the subspace of $\mathscr{H}$ consisting of non-singleton sets of the form $S_F$ for some $F$ as above.

Now for $A,B\in\mathscr{F}$, write $A\perp B$ iff there are finite sets of contraction maps $F,G$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a nonempty compact set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ with $dim(X)=2$ such that $$A=S_F, B=S_G,F[X]\cup G[X]=X,\mbox{ and }dim(F[X]\cap G[X])<2.$$ (The specific notion of dimension shouldn't matter here, but to be precise I'll use [covering dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension).) From $\perp$ we get an equivalence relation: say that $A$ and $B$ are **plementary** *(eliding an initial "m" for ease of pronunciation)*, and write $A\sim B$, iff there is an even-length sequence $C_1,C_2,...,C_{2k-1}, C_{2k}\in\mathscr{F}$ with $C_1=A$, $C_{2k}=B$, and $C_i\perp C_{i+1}$ for each $1\le i<2k$. My question is:

> **Q1**: How many classes does $\sim$ partition $\mathscr{F}$ into?

"Obviously" the answer is continuum-many ... right?

---

Here are a couple follow-up questions which might be easier to tackle:

> **Q2.1**: Suppose the Hausdorff dimensions of $A$ and $B$ are mutually transcendental. Must we have $A\not\sim B$?

(I suspect the answer is yes, which would give an answer to Q1, but I don't see how to prove it. The specific choice of Hausdorff dimension here is more-or-less random; any reasonable fractal dimension can be used here in its place if that would simplify things.)

> **Q2.2**: Are the Sierpinski *triangle* and *carpet* plementary?

(I suspect the answer here is no, but again, I don't see how to prove it.)

More generally, I'm interested in any not-too-hard-to-calculate invariants that help distinguish $\sim$-classes.